# PHP Get Access an Token from Gotowebinar API

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, php-curl

I try using PHP to get an access token in GoToWebinar API, from this documentation https://developer.goto.com/guides/HowTos/03_HOW_accessToken/

here my php script

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/token",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Basic MWM4ODE2MmItMGZkZS00YTM4LWI0NGMtMWMzOGFhMDY5YmI4OktQSDg2d1hnVUM5a0FqbithMVBsOGc9PQ==',
'Accept: application/json',
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"redirect_uri=http://indotourismevents.com/webinar&grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJraWQiOiJvYXV0aHYyLmxtaS5jb20uMDIxOSIsImFsZyI6IlJTNTEyIn0.eyJscyI6IjczYjkyNzhmLTBmNjMtNDE3NC1iYTljLWE3ZTIyYzIwMDhmNyIsInVyaSI6Imh0dHA6Ly9pbmRvdG91cmlzbWV2ZW50cy5jb20vd2ViaW5hci8iLCJzYyI6ImNvbGxhYjogaWRlbnRpdHk6c2NpbS5tZSBpZGVudGl0eToiLCJhdWQiOiIxYzg4MTYyYi0wZmRlLTRhMzgtYjQ0Yy0xYzM4YWEwNjliYjgiLCJzdWIiOiIzODc4MTIxOTUzODYzNTgxMTkwIiwianRpIjoiOTgyYTYyMWQtYTFhYi00NTE3LWFlYTgtNDFlYmY3OWE0NzFlIiwiZXhwIjoxNTk0NzQxOTUxLCJpYXQiOjE1OTQ3NDEzNTEsInR5cCI6ImMifQ.Cy6TR18iKmCtotZnnPvMUS9QMh4EFBP6FMcqBOWN9LtricreNg1qnA45UJB0cQALB1d5h9zgc-nDkU4GtTNr8ZnDSI26On3YqFJBICptmfrHhI7ZZIwH-p8YilKirHua1shEPVpradyAj_epjfmejd35QbCXD8aTz3uq-ocRGZFvz0WZfAA7wWryMBnkvTm5BM4fTx99Q4AGfT27QFomaR4hGsLy6uUM4N3rcqP7VNM21XeuIZ-5U1zd2Ew0-gnWoNo8lOF1hJeihZ_xyMlY9AgN7HAwW55JmUkFSsNVHdLznYebzXuDJZXGYnXxQwIyVym3tmx88JRUcI0bMzJ5-w",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
```

from the documentation, curl must give some header and form body

```
curl -X POST "https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/token" \
-H "Authorization: Basic YTIwfAKeNGYtODY4YS00MzM5LTkzNGYtNGRhMmQ3ODhkMGFhOjNuYU8xMElBMmFnY3ZHKzlJOVRHRVE9PQ==" \
-H "Accept:application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "redirect_uri=https://example.com&grant_type=authorization_code&code=iS0vynEEvRFA9i6kZ8gvNDnnOGE..."
```

and i give all required header&form body, but still return an error like this

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Required parameter(s) missing or wrong."}
```

how to PHP get access token from GoToWebinar API?

Comment: FYI, you were missing "client_id" in your request. The documentation for G2W is ALL OVER THE PLACE, so I don't blame you for missing it.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I also added the client_id but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem when I logged in with the same user account to G2Webinar as my developer user (the oauth client's user was the same as the user webinar user)
Try to register another account.